# How to make entered text appear on the screen

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a <textarea> element in my HTML, and I have a send button. When you press that send button, the text in the <textarea> element should appear on the screen.
I tried putting this JavaScript code in my head section:

```
<script>
        function displayText(element, change_to) {
            document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = document.getElementById(change_to).innerHTML
        }
    </script>
```

And this is the body section:

```
<body>
    <p id="msg"></p>
    <textarea id="enterMsg"></textarea>
    <button id="sendButton" onclick="displayText('msg', 'enterMsg')">Send</button>
</body>
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: You're pretty close, but to get the value of a textarea you need to use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Or, in most (modern) browsers, `textContent` and `innerText` also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `value` property for the *textarea* element. I will also suggest you use `innerText` or `textContent` if the value is plain text (not *htmlString*):

```html
<script>
    function displayText(element, change_to) {
        document.getElementById(element).textContent = document.getElementById(change_to).value
    }
</script>

<body>
    <p id="msg"></p>
    <textarea id="enterMsg"></textarea>
    <button id="sendButton" onclick="displayText('msg', 'enterMsg')">Send</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh, so textarea doesn't have innerHTML or textContent but value. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidBagel, yes, exactly:)

Comment: Are there other elements that use value instead of textContent or innerHTML?

Comment: @DavidBagel, normally all input elements have the value property, all other elements have textContent. innerText and innerHTML:)

Answer (score 0):

textarea don't have innerHTML, you should use .value instead

Comment: It does have an `innerHTML` but it is not the content that you enter. The `innerHTML` is the part between the open en closing tag.